# removing white space on a page between sections separated by a div

Tags: html, css

**my html for spacer**

```
<main>
   <section>...
   </section><div class="spacer layer1">
   </div><section>...
   </section>
</main>
```

**my css for spacer**

```
.spacer {
    aspect-ratio: 1080/300;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.layer1 {
    background-image: url(waves/col1.svg);
    border-top: 2px solid #d96459;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f2ae72;
}
```

the issue :
[image]

the white space as shown seems to appear and disappear based on width on a computer screen while it stays on the mobile screen as shown in the picture.

I can't seem to find a workaround. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try to inspect the elements in browser dev tools to see what element is responsible for the breaks. I suspect it has something to do with the SVG scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your SVG fills the entire viewbox, my guess is that the scaling sometimes results in the edges landing on fractional screen pixel boundaries.

Assuming you're seeing a transparent gap (as opposed to a white-ish rendering artifact) you might be able to use a negative vertical margins on the spacer to create a pixel or two of overlap.

```css
section {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
}

.spacer {
  margin: -5px 0; /* exaggerated for visibility. probably don't need this much.  */
  background: bisque;
  opacity: .5; /* so you can see the overlap */
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<section></section>
```

Comment: I was able to overcome it automatically. The problem lied with the aspect ratio. So for awkward ratios the gap seems visible. Either way thank you so much for the solution. I'll be sure to implement and check it.